# Why does a system being in an $s$-wave mean that the spatial wavefunction is symmetric? Does it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, symmetry, parity, identical-particles

Probably being silly here, but me and my fellow undergrads can't seem to come up with an exact answer to why, if a system is in an $s$-wave, *edit: or any orbital with an even value of $\ell$*, the spacial wf must be symmetric under exchange of like particles.

Also, what is the relationship between the symmetry of a particles wavefunction and its parity? Another one that doesn't seem to have a clear-cut answer among us!

Comment: $s$-wave means angular momentum $0$.  Can you construct spatial wf that are not symmetric with angular momentum $0$?  Have you tried with $2$ or $3$ particles?

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between exchange symmetry and parity is something that has also greatly confused me. Definitions:

- Parity refers to whether a quantum state picks up a minus sign when
  all the *spatial* coordinates are inverted, rather like an even or
  odd function.
- Exchange symmetry refers to whether the combined state for a system
  of two particles picks up a minus sign when the particle labels are
  exchanged.

At first, there seems to be no obvious link between these two symmetries.

Let's begin with parity. In spherical polar coordinates, a parity transformation is equivalent to $\theta \rightarrow \pi-\theta$, $\phi \rightarrow \pi+\phi$ with $r$ remaining the same. In any system with spherical symmetry, the part of the spatial wavefunction which depends on $\theta$ and $\phi$ is given by the spherical harmonics $Y^M_L(\theta, \phi)$. It can be shown that the spherical harmonics have parity

$$Y^M_L(-{\bf r})=(-1)^LY^M_L({\bf r})$$

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Symmetry_properties). Thus, the spatial wavefunction will have parity $(-1)^L$.

Exchange symmetry is more complicated. Since you are interested in the exchange symmetry of the *spatial* wavefunction, we can ignore spin and only think about orbital angular momentum. Let the two individual particles have orbital angular momentum eigenstates $\vert j_1 m_1 \rangle$ and $\vert j_2 m_2\rangle$. The eigenstates of the combined system of two particles are then

$$\vert LM\rangle = \sum_{m_1}\sum_{m_2}C^{LM}_{j_1m_1;j_2m_2} \vert j_1 m_1 \rangle \vert j_2 m_2 \rangle \tag{1}$$

where $C^{LM}_{j_1 m_1;j_2 m_2}$ are the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients. The Clebsch-Gordan coefficients have well-defined exchange symmetry given by

$$C^{LM}_{j_2 m_2; j_1 m_1}=(-1)^{j_1+j_2-L}C^{LM}_{j_1 m_1;j_2 m_2}$$

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Symmetry_properties). Let's assume that the two particles have the same $j_1 = j_2 = j$. The exchange symmetry factor then becomes

$$(-1)^{2j-L}.$$

This factor can be taken outside the sum in equation (1), so also gives the exchange symmetry of $\vert LM\rangle$. Since $2j$ is even, the exchange symmetry of the spatial wavefunction is

$$(-1)^L$$

AHA! We have found that both the parity and exchange symmetry of the spatial wavefunction are given by $(-1)^L$. However, this has arisen from the assumption that $j_1=j_2$, so there doesn't seem to be a deep connection between these two symmetries.